# Set images in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a listActivity. In each row of the list a name of a category is placed.

I download the activities from the web, so they may change occasionally. But I would like to set a image to each category.

I have a list of categories that may occur. And I have graphics for all categories. How can I match the correct image with corresponding category in a smooth way?

EDIT:

I have the pictures. And now how to add them to a listView. But Im looking for advice how to map a correct category to a correct picture. Could a bitmap factory do the trick, if I name the pictures to the same as the categories.

```
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/categoryicon_"+c.getId() + ".png");
                                imageView.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it like this:

```
String icon = "category_"+c.getId();
                                int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(icon, "drawable", getPackageName());
                                Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resId);
                                imageView.setImageBitmap(bMap)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try a map with the category names as key and the resource id of the image as value. Then you can load a drawable from the resources using the right id.

Comment: That could work. But it's not very scalable. Lets say I have 100 categories...Im looking into bitmaps, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

For displaying the activities, I would use a custom array adapter, there are so many different examples out there so you will find loads if you just google. [List14](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html) is a really good example to start with. 
Then you have an array of activities, each activity has an id which decides what kind of image that will be shown, and of course the name of the activity. Then just depending on which id the activity has display the correct image.

If you would like to change it occasionally with refresh from a homepage you should probably download the images and store them in a good manner, if the image changes with the activities of course.

Answer (score 0):

I would try and a map with the category names. Then i would use the resource id of the image as the value. Then you could load the images using the right ID.

If you want to add a imageview to a ListView you will also need to use a custom array adapter

This is an example of how you would do it.

This is a good one to get you started

http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/using-arrayadapter-and-listview-in-android-applications